# Getting 400 bad request in wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am getting 400 bad request when clicking the button from plugin. Is there any missing function? please advise on this.

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type : "POST",
     dataType : "json",
     url : "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
     data : {action: "get_process_payment"},
     success: function(response) {
       alert("Your vote could not be added");
       alert(response);
     }
}); 

function get_process_payment(){
   echo "test";
   wp_die();
}
```

Comment: where is your `get_process_payment` function

Comment: How to call endpoint url of plugin function in wordpress

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress,
`wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)` executes for users that are not logged in.
if you want it to fire on the front-end for both visitors and logged-in users, you can do this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );
```

So in your example add like this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_get_process_payment', 'get_process_payment' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_process_payment', 'get_process_payment' );
function get_process_payment(){
   echo "test";
   wp_die();
}
```

Please check https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins for more details

Comment: actualy i am doing a custom payment gateway plugin all the scripts are in payment field hook https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401434/how-to-get-the-plugin-end-point-url-in-woocommerce-plugin-class-itself