# Getting 400 bad request on wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=mypage_hook

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have customized some payment gateway plugin to use another payment provider.
I am using the hosted payment page service and until now I've completed the process of the redirect to the payment page and get the payment.
The issue is once complete or takes any action on the hosting payment page it triggers a web-hook that post the results back to custom URL.

Have tried to post these data back to secure page on the same plugin DIR but it didn't work giving me 400 bad request.

```
<?php

// If loading directly, make sure we return a 200 HTTP status
global $isapage;
$isapage = true;

//in case the file is loaded directly
if ( ! defined( "ABSPATH" ) ) {
    define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/../../../../wp-load.php' );
}
```

I don't what I've missed here or if there is any other method to get the response back.

Comment: It maybe related with the AJAX request. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414918/getting-400-bad-request-in-wordpress-plugin

Comment: This is not the code that is causing your problem

Comment: Yes you're right, have discovered the issue and the hook is not registered and loaded in the plugin to be called.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to comments by @ozgur have solved by:

```
/**
 * register the webhook to be activated
 */
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myhook_webhook', 'wp_ajax_myhook_webhook');
add_action('wp_ajax_myhook_webhook', 'wp_ajax_myhook_webhook');

function wp_ajax_myhook_webhook()
{
    require_once(plugin_DIR. "/services/myhook-webhook.php");   
    exit;   
}
```